# USBasp AvrStudio dillema

Tags: avrdude, avr-studio6

I have a problem trying to integrate USBasp with avr studio. I have not been able to solve it yet, still get this error:
avrdude.exe: invalid file format '\' in update specifier
avrdude.exe: error parsing update operation

Could someone help me?

This is my command: C:\avrdude-5.11-Patch7610-win32\avrdude.exe

and my argument is: -c usbasp -p atmega168 -U flash:w:"$(ProjectDir)Debug\$(ItemFileName).hex"

I get the same error with command line mode.

Thanks in advance,
Andrew

Answer (score 0):

For mega168:

- **USBasp_mega168_write**

  -c usbasp -p m168 -U flash:w:"$(ProjectDir)Debug\$(TargetName).hex":i
- **USBasp_mega168_read**

  -c usbasp -p m168
- **USBasp_mega168_erase**

  -c usbasp -p m168 -B 0.5 -e

Your mistake is this:

> -c usbasp -p ***atmega168*** -U flash:w:"$(ProjectDir)Debug\$(ItemFileName).hex"